# TcpDump capture stops after few minutes. (Windows)

Tags: networking, sniffing, tcpdump

I'm trying to capture all my networking with tcpdump.

I'm using tcpdump.exe -i {} -W 5 -C 10 -w capfile. After 10 mints (+-) the capture stopped for some reason, and tcpdump is still running.

Maybe there is a parameter for how much time to capture? I Know the -G parameter, but it's rotate the pcap files.

If someone know why it's happened and how can I fix that, to capture for unlimited time I will be grateful :)

**I'm using tcpdump.exe on windows.**

By the way, there is any way to use -i "eth0" on windows? Because on windows I need to check my interface number and use it like this -i "3".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`-C 10` limits the size of the file to 10 MB.
After the first `capfile` file is full, numbered `capfile` files will be added.

`-W 5` limits the number of these files to 5, after which
it begins overwriting files from the beginning as a rotating buffer.

I believe tcpdump is still working, busily overwriting its five
"`capfile`` files.

See : [Manpage of TCPDUMP](https://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html).

Comment: I know the parameters.

Comment: I know the parameters. 
But the capfile doesn't change, it's doesn't overwriting the five file, it's just stop the capture, I saw the five "capfile" but after few mints the file doesn't change any more, The "Date modified" doesn't change any more.

Comment: I suggest that you copy the 5 files, wait an hour, then compare the contents to see if it is really hang. If instead of rotation it stops, then this is a bug. I don't exactly know where you may report it, perhaps at [tcpdump.org](http://www.tcpdump.org/). In the meantime, you may avoid circular buffers if that is indeed the buggy feature.